# Devise textbox formatting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

After setting up devise for my log-in page i was wondering how to adjust the size of f.email_field and f.password_field height please? I have tried

Comment: not sure if u have tried the plugin's https://github.com/jessedearing/html5_rails2_plugin

Comment: I've tried :width => 20 for example and that makes the textbox longer...which i don't want to do and :height => 20 has no effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What have you tried? You can generate devise views with

```
$ rails generate devise:views
```

and edit them afterwards.

Comment: ya that's what i used to set up the login and that's all perfect, it's just the html of the 2 textboxs in which the user enters their email and password in to login. I just want to increase their height...I don't know how to do this I've tried :width => 20 for example and that makes the textbox longer however :height => 20 has no effect?

Comment: I'm not completely sure about this but I think you can give them a `class: 'myclass'` to be used in CSS to style them, you could even give a class to the form and then use `input` on the css file to style it.

Comment: Here is the code: <div class = "space"><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>.....so it's the f.email_field :email part I'm trying to edit for the height.

Comment: Try giving both of them a `class: "registration_input"` and then apply styles in the according CSS file.

Comment: <div class = "space"><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <div class ="textbox"><%= f.password_field :password %></div></div>             So this is what i entered in the CSS                                 .login .space .textbox {
 font-size:40px
} (login was the first class that i didn't paste in the above code.

Comment: By giving a class to them I meant, actually giving a class to the form item, not to the div containing it: `<%= f.label :password, class: "input_field" %>` and then use `.input_field { font-size:40px }` I'm not sure about the CSS itself but you should be able to style it this way.

Comment: Wow great thanks a million that works a treat!! Thanks again to all of ye for the help:)

Comment: No problem! You can accept this answer so other people with same trouble find it easier :)

Answer (score 0):

To edit devise view pages you need to go into your devise.rb file in initializer folder.

uncomment line 181 and change it from

```
config.scoped_views = false
```

to this

```
config.scoped_views = true
```

you should be able to edit the view files any way you want

To increase the size of your input field you will need to increase your font. declare a font-size for your input field. i.e font-size: 50px;

Comment: Hi iRichLau, but I was able to change the width of the textbox without editing the devise.rb file, however, I was unable to change the height.

Comment: increase your font size bro

Comment: tried and tested it does not read font-size => 20px it just causes an error on the page